# Aligning Google Plus One and Facebook Like buttons properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, google-plus

I am trying to put a Google Plus One and a Facebook Like button inline next to each other. For some reason the Facebook like button has a gap at the top which moves it down by a few pixels and makes it look funny.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/yF4yz/

Is there a better way to align these two buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the css styles are being loaded with the images. You can either set the css on your page ( recommended ) or in javascript, do a document on load, and change the values once the images are populated.

Adding this css will move the facebook icon up 3 pixels, and to the left 25 pixels, next to the google icon.

```
div.fb-like
{
    top:-3px;
    left:-25px;
}
```

Comment: -4 looks to align slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/yF4yz/8/